# Creating a pass through function in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am curious how to create a typed function that allows you to pass the types of the function entered through as the return type and the arguments.

```
const preventDefault = function <T> (passThroughFunction: T) {
  return function (event, ...args): ReturnType<typeof T> {
    event.preventDefault();
    return passThroughFunction(...[event, ...args]);
  } 
}
```

This is broken. I am not sure how to use ReturnType properly or extract the arguments from `passThroughFunction` and include them in the returned function.

So I can use it like this:

```
<Button onSubmit={preventDefault(onSubmit)}/>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want information about which event called the preventDefault function ?

Answer (score 1):

I think here you are better of not using the conditional types. They would require type assertions in the implementation (since conditional types are not resolved as long as they still have free type parameters)

This will work, and will actually allow contextual types to flow from the assignment target to the function you define, so if you use inline functions you will get parameter type inference

```
const preventDefault = function <E extends SyntheticEvent, A extends any[], R> (passThroughFunction: (e: E, ...a: A) => R) {
  return function (event: E, ...args: A): R {
    event.preventDefault();
    return passThroughFunction(event, ...args);
  } 
}

let o = () => <button onClick={preventDefault(e => e.movementX)}></button>
let o2 = () => <div onKeyDown={preventDefault(e => e.keyCode)}></div>
```